# For loop in django retrieving all users instead of one and M2M field data output

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, django-templates

I have 2 Issues in Django:

1. Below are my codes, whenever I am using For loop in my Template, it is retrieving not one user data, but all users/profile data. but when I use request.user.profile.first_name only then it works, but I am in a situation where I need to retrieve data from the many-to-many fields and I have to use For loop, which brings me to my 2nd question
2. I need to use For loop in the many-to-many field to retrieve the data, but it is fetching for all users, please can you correct me where I am doing wrong? or is there an alternate method to retrieve data without using for loop (one user/profile only post-logging-in)

**models.py**

```
class Department(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   
   def __str__(self):
       return self.name

class Profile(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   email = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   departments = models.ManyToManyField(Department)
```

**views.py**

```
def profilepage(request):
    profiles = Profile.objects.all()
    departments = Department.objects.all()
    context = {
        'profiles': profiles,
        'departments': departments
    }
    return render(request, 'profile.html', context)
```

**profile.html**

```
{% for profile in profiles %}
First Name: {{profile.first_name}}
   {% for department in departments %}
      Department: {{department.name}}
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the departments of a `Profile` with:

```
{% for profile in profiles %}
First Name: {{ profile.first_name }}
   {% for department in profile.departments.all %}
      Department: {{ department.name  }}
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

In order to boost performance, you can use [**`.prefetch_related(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) to fetch all the related departments with one extra query, instead of one query *per* profile:

```
def profilepage(request):
    profiles = Profile.objects.prefetch_related('departments')
    context = {
        'profiles': profiles
    }
    return render(request, 'profile.html', context)
```

> 1. (…) I use `request.user.profile.first_name`.

You can pass a single profile to the template with:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def profilepage(request):
    profile = request.user.profile
    context = {
        'profile': profile
    }
    return render(request, 'profile.html', context)
```

and then render it without enumerating over the `profiles` so *without* a `{% for ... %}` loop:

```
First Name: {{ profile.first_name }}
   {% for department in profile.departments.all %}
      Department: {{ department.name  }}
   {% endfor %}
```

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a view to authenticated users with the
> [**`@login_required`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).